# C++ face detection combined with c# WPF

Tags: c++, opencv

I downloaded and studied a code in C++, where Caffe and OpenCV are used for Face Recognition. At the moment, the code is written as a Console Application, that opens a window with the "Livestream" of the webcam and the face recognition.

Now i read that if I want to add the program to WPF, I need to make the C++ part a DLL, that gets implemented into C#. But my problem atm is this code:

```
int init(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  char acUserName[100];
  string UserName;
  DWORD nUserName = sizeof(acUserName);
  if (GetUserName(acUserName, &nUserName)) {
  UserName = acUserName;


string errorPath = "C:/Users/" + UserName + "/Desktop/ErrorLog.txt";
const char *errorChars = errorPath.c_str();

...
}
```

I found this code for getting the current username in c++, the init method is actually the main, just with a new name. But when I type this code in my DLL-version, Visual Studio gives the Error

```
argument of type "char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"
```

and the "acUserName" in

```
if (GetUserName(acUserName, &nUserName))
```

is marked. How can I fix this?

(I'm beginner in C++, if you guys need more code, tell me)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like charset error.try to change charset to `multibyte` in VisualStudio Project Setting.

Answer (score 0):

There are wide-string and ASCII versions for API functions, which have 'W' or 'A' appended to the function name respectively. The `GetUserName` uses the wide-string variant by default.

If you don't care about Multibyte character strings, you can use `GetUserNameA`, with the parameters: `&UserName[0]` and the predefined length of the string.

However if you do, then just change the type of `UserName` to a `wstring`, and then pass the parameters to the function in the same way. Don't forget to include 'wstring.h' as well.